# Check for pending files in perforce and if files are in pending list go to eof, if not Do something

Tags: batch-file, cmd, perforce

I am trying to find all the pendinglist files in my perforce depoth opened by me and if there are some pendingfiles in the pendinglist I want to execute `:eof` funtion, if not I want to `do something`

I tried like this

```
@echo off
cls
set P4CLIENT=<Workspace_name>
set P4PORT=<IPadress:port>
set P4USER=%username%

set Depot_Path=//Depoth/path/...

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('p4 opened -u %username% //Depoth/path/...') DO set open_files=%%i
echo %open_files%

if %open_files% =="" (
    echo No file are in pendig list
    goto execute
    ) else (
        echo files are in pending list, please submit them if needed or revert them 
        echo %open_files%
        goto eof
    )

:execute
<Do something>
:eof
```

When I execute the above script. I can see the opened files printed on the console but after that the script throwing an error as **- was unexpected at this time.**

What should I do to get **if there are some pendingfiles in the pendinglist I want to execute `:eof` funtion, if not I want to `do something`**

Comment: You should definitely change, `echo %open_files%` and `if %open_files% ==""`, to `echo(%open_files%` and `if "%open_files%" ==""` respectively. As you have already defined `Depot_Path`, you should be using it in your `p4` command, as `"%Depot_Path%"`. Additionally, you should use the recommended method of defining variables, i.e `Set "VarName=Var string value"`. Finally, do not use `:eof` in your file. `:EOF` is by default, the end of file marker, not a standard label, so just remove it, the parser will know what irt means, and where to go.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know Perforce very well, but `.bat` syntax barely at all.  I have no real idea of what any of that `FOR` line is doing beyond the very general notion that it's iterating over the output of `p4 opened`.

I *think* the issue is that your script expects `p4 opened` to print just the filename, when the reality is that it prints output like this:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 opened ...
//stream/test/bar#1 - edit default change (text)
```

The error you're seeing is probably due to that `FOR` statement trying to parse that line of output and tripping over the `-` character.

A very easy fix is to use `p4`'s `-F` global option to reformat the output into just the file path:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -F %depotFile% opened ...
//stream/test/bar
```

hence:

```
@echo off
cls

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('p4 -F ^%depotFile^% opened ...') DO set open_files=%%i
echo %open_files%

if %open_files% =="" (
    echo No file are in pendig list
    goto execute
    ) else (
        echo files are in pending list, please submit them if needed or revert them 
        echo %open_files%
        goto eof
    )

:execute
<Do something>
:eof
```

prints:

```
opened
files are in pending list, please submit them if needed or revert them
opened
```